# Is it possible for a page be in two working sets at the same time?

Tags: operating-system, computer-science

Is it possible for a page be in two working sets at the same time?
I feel like it shouldn't be possible as a page being shared by 2 working sets could become problematic.

Comment: If it's a code page or other read-only page, sure, why not?

Comment: This is precisely how shared libraries work.